# How to use ST_GeoHash and ST_MakePoint postgis functions in rails before save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgis

How to build in rails postgis point, then geohash and save them into database before send response to client? I would like to make it through `ST_MakePoint` and `ST_GeoHash` function, I prefer to avoid execute SQL and extracting data by `[0]["st_makepoint"]`, if it is possible how to insert this functions to execute them automatically when inserting all attributes? I've installed squeel gem, maybe can I merge this functions to the query?

My current rails code:

```
before_save :set_geopoint
def set_geopoint
  #attributes -> {"latitude" => 51.90,"longitude" => 16.42,"geopoint" => nil}
  #self.geopoint = "ST_MakePoint(#{latitude}, #{longitude})")" #not working
  #self.geopoint = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT ST_MakePoint(#{latitude}, #{longitude})")[0]["st_makepoint"]
  #self.geohash = "ST_GeoHash(#{self.geopoint})"
  #self.geohash = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT ST_GeoHash(ST_SetSRID(#{self.geopoint},4326),5);").first["st_geohash"]
end
```

I did it through SQL before trigger function but I'm still looking for rails approach.

```
CREATE FUNCTION geopoint_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO posts( geopoint ) VALUES( ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || NEW.latitude || ' ' ||  NEW.longitude || ')') );
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on "not working"?

Comment: @MikeT in this line `ST_MakePoint` is ignored and after save geopoint is stored as nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate a point that you can save in a postgis enabled database, you need to generate that point with a factory. What you're doing here:

```
self.geopoint = "ST_MakePoint(#{latitude}, #{longitude})")" #not working
```

is just setting `self.geopoint` to a string and trying to save it. As your database geopoint field is (I assume) set to accept a point, it fails.

I suggest you use the rgeo gem to add geo factories to your models. Add it to your `Gemfile`.

https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo

You need to make sure that in your migration, you are using a point as column type like this:

```
t.point :geopoint, geographic: true
```

In your `Post` model, you then need to specify a factory like this:

```
RGEO_FACTORY = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326)
```

And you also need to tell rgeo what factory to use on your `geopoint` column.

```
set_rgeo_factory_for_column :geopoint, RGEO_FACTORY
```

Now in your `before_save`, simply do:

```
self.geopoint = RGEO_FACTORY.point(latitude, longitude)
```

and it should work...

**EDIT**

If you want to use Postgis functions in your Rails models to get the `GeoHash` for instance, then you could do something like this:

```
post_geohash = Post.select("ST_GeoHash(geopoint) as geohash").where(id: some_post_id).geohash
```

You could also create an instance method that does that on your Post model:

```
def geohash
  Post.select("ST_GeoHash(geopoint) as geohash").where(id: id).geohash
end
```

Not sure this works as it's not tested but you get the idea.

Comment: What if I want to create and add to my function, eg. `ST_GeoHash` to generate string from this point, so I don't want to use RGeo gem only postgis functions, unless if I can create this way other types of geodata?

Comment: You can create different shapes with rgeo and do simple queries with the activerecord postgis adapter. I don't think there is any support for GeoHash in the adapter yet but there is already quite a lot. Remember that Postgis is a postgresql extension and that you will need to write your own postgis SQL queries if you want to do complex things. The postgis adapter and rgeo are just there to help you do basic things, it's not a full postgis query interface. Check the doc http://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter http://github.com/rgeo/rgeo

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to execute also other Postgis functions, in my example Point is just an example of how to use sql function without an adapter if it is possible.

Comment: I think the issue is clearer now. I have to do this before save, if the Post isn't saved and hasn't yet id than I have to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`, what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: If you want to do it in a before save my guess is that you need a ruby based way to generate the data. Postgis won't be of much help unless you use a trigger like you do. But I'm not a big fan as it puts logic in the database and may make it implicit and opaque to other devs.